# Select and concatenate dict value lists

Tags: ansible

I've got a dict of lists like this:

```yaml
packages:
  server:
    - foo
    - bar
    - baz
  client:
    - spam
    - ham
    - eggs
  runtime:
    - corge
    - grault
    - garply
```

and I want to generate a list by defining keys to select in another dict, so e.g.:

```yaml
enable:
  server: true
  client: false
  runtime: true
```

would result in:

```yaml
output:
  - foo
  - bar
  - baz
  - corge
  - grault
  - garply
```

Any ideas how to do this in ansible/jinja?? Ideally without using the `loop` construct but I could live with that. I suspect it'll need an intermediate variable and so far all I've got is something to extract a list of the keys from `enable` which have a `true` value:

```
- set_fact:
   enabled: "{{ (enable | dict2items | selectattr('value')  | list | items2dict).keys() }}"
```

If this looks a bit convoluted its because both `packages` and `enable` are existing role variables which I'd prefer not to change. But open to suggestions (especially on `packages`) if reshaping them makes this much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's create the list of enabled hosts first. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_hosts: "{{ enable|dict2items|
                      selectattr('value')|
                      map(attribute='key')|list }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_hosts
```

give

```yaml
  my_hosts:
  - server
  - runtime
```

Then use this list to [extract](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#extracting-values-from-containers) the packages. For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_list: "{{ my_hosts|map('extract', packages)|list|flatten }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_list
```

give

```yaml
  my_list:
  - foo
  - bar
  - baz
  - corge
  - grault
  - garply
```

---

The single task below comprises both steps

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_list: "{{ my_hosts|map('extract', packages)|list|flatten }}"
      vars:
        my_hosts: "{{ enable|dict2items|
                      selectattr('value')|
                      map(attribute='key')|list }}"
```

Comment: What's `my_hosts` in that answer please?

Comment: Ahh brilliant, thank you for the detailed explanation too.